# Mod Rewrite на NGINX не отдает CSS

Tags: nginx, mod_rewrite

Здравствуйте. На сервере Debian 6, Nginx и PHP через FastCGI. Используется фреймворк. Он требует Mod Rewrite. На своем ноутбуке стоял Apache, на нем все работало хорошо. На сервере скрипты работают но нет доступа к файлам таблиц стилей (.css), на запрос к ним сервер отвечает ошибкой 404, в итоге вся верстка сползает. Вот конфиг nginx.conf:

```
user www-data www-data;worker_processes  5;error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;events {    worker_connections  1024;    # multi_accept on;}http {    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;    sendfile        on;    #tcp_nopush     on;    #keepalive_timeout  0;    keepalive_timeout  65;    tcp_nodelay        on;    gzip  on;    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;}# mail {#     # See sample authentication script at:#     # http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript# #     # auth_http localhost/auth.php;#     # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";#     # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";# #     server {#         listen     localhost:110;#         protocol   pop3;#         proxy      on;#     }# #     server {#         listen     localhost:143;#         protocol   imap;#         proxy      on;#     }# }
```

Файл конфигурации сайта:

```
server {    listen 176.58.120.223:80;    server_name ***.ru;    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;    location / {        root /srv/nginx/***/www/;        index index.htm index.html index.php;        autoindex off;        # don’t check $uri/, send to php for nice error message        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;    }    location ~ \.php$ {        root           /srv/nginx/***/www/;        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;        fastcgi_index  index.php;        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /srv/nginx/***/www/$fastcgi_script_name;        include        fastcgi_params;    }}
```

Посоветуйте что поправить, или хотя бы куда копать. Спасибо.

UPD:

Запрашиваю *домен*/css/bootstrap.css

Срабатывает *домен*/index.php/css/bootstrap.css

Фреймворк отрабатывает, и выводит ошибку 404.

Comment: А причем тут rewrite. Кому он нужен то?

Comment: Ок. А чего реврайтить то надо, задача rewrite какая?

Comment: А в error логе при этом что?

Comment: я просто к тому что бы посмотреть по какому пути выпадает 404, что бы это путь замапить location-ом!

Comment: А имя домена или IP адрес не менялись? Очень похоже, что где-то не тот адрес застрял.

Comment: Увидел UPD. А что там в index.php?

Comment: Это файл фреймворка, он передает управление дальше, записывая переданные ему параметры, суть в том что при запросе *домен*/контроллер/экшен он запускает класс *контроллер* и вызывает в нем метод *экшен*. А запросы на статические файлы к index.php по идее не должны попадать

Comment: Да ну? Если по HTTP туда заходить, то именно index.php первым и будет обработан. Попробуйте его переименовать, и сообщите что будет!

Comment: Я о том что запрос *домен*/css/bootstrap.cssне должен редиректится на *домен*/index.php/css/bootstrap.cssа редиректит NGINX

Comment: Так index.php в секции location конфигурации сайта явно объявлен!

Comment: В вопросе я и спросил, что поправить?, т.к. настройки NGINX для меня китайская грамота, раньше всегда APACHE использовал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть, в этом дело:

> fastcgi_index
>
> syntax: fastcgi_index имя
>
> default: нет
>
> context: http, server, location
>
> Директива задаёт имя файла, которыйпри создании переменной$fastcgi_script_name будет добавлятьсяпосле URI, если URI заканчиваетсяслэшом.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, решил проблему добавлением строчек:location ~* \.css|\.js|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif|\.swf|\.svg|\.tiff|\.pdf$ {    root /srv/nginx/***/www/;}До этого не получалось потому что NGINX не перезапускался (повис в зомбоках).